# Connect webpage to rds using Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am creating a ec2 with rds (mysql). In the config file given in the user data I want to give the rds endpoint. How to I refer to the endpoint here`'DB_SERVER', '**Endpoint of db**'` to connect the ec2 instance webpage to the rds

Note: I am creating rds in the same yml file just want to give REF to the endpoint to the config file that I am echoing using Userdata

```
 EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
           echo "<?php

           define('DB_SERVER', '**Endpoint of db**');
           define('DB_USERNAME', 'shifadb');
           define('DB_PASSWORD', 'shifa123a');
           define('DB_DATABASE', 'shifadb');

           ?>" > dbinfo.inc
          
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            DeleteOnTermination: "true"
            VolumeSize: "8"
            VolumeType: gp2
      ImageId: ami-0bdcc6c05dec346bf
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref ListS3BucketsInstanceProfile
      KeyName: webserver
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - Description: Primary network interface
          DeviceIndex: 0
          SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA
          GroupSet:
            - Ref: webserver
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would do this through using [return values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#aws-properties-rds-database-instance-return-values) for the `AWS::RDS::DBInstance` resource.

For example, if you have RDS instance:

```
Resources:

  MyDBInstance:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
    Properties: {}
```

then you can access MyDBInstance's  `Endpoint.Address` as follows:

```
UserData:
    Fn::Base64: !Sub |
      #!/bin/bash
       echo "<?php

       define('DB_SERVER', '${MyDBInstance.Endpoint.Address}');
       define('DB_USERNAME', 'shifadb');
       define('DB_PASSWORD', 'shifa123a');
       define('DB_DATABASE', 'shifadb');

       ?>" > dbinfo.inc
```

Similarly for the `Endpoint.Port` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have added this function that gets the db dns and connects it.`define('DB_SERVER', '!GetAtt MyDB.DNSName');` for more information read this https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html